# Using Orbit Slider with Reverie WordPress Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, zurb-foundation, orbit

I'm trying to use the [Orbit Slider](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html) with [Reverie WordPress Framework](http://themefortress.com/reverie/).

I've used the basic format to set up the Orbit Slider as provided in the Orbit Documentation:

```
<ul class="example-orbit" data-orbit>
  <li>
    <img src="../assets/img/examples/satelite-orbit.jpg" alt="slide 1" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">
      Caption One.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    <img src="../assets/img/examples/andromeda-orbit.jpg" alt="slide 2" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">
      Caption Two.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="../assets/img/examples/launch-orbit.jpg" alt="slide 3" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">
      Caption Three.
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

However, I can't seem to make it work.

I've used the following scripts:

```
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation-js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fastclick-js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'masonry-js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'html5shiv' );
```

And have called the foolowing from the footer:

```
    <script>
        (function($) {
            $(document).foundation();
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Do I need to call the Orbit Slider also from the footer like this:

```
    $(document).foundation('orbit', 'reflow');
```

I've done that too but it didn't work.

Also, I was using the default Jquery provided with WordPress but that too didn't work so I'm using the `jquery version 2.1.0`.

I've used `foundation.min.js`. So, I don't think that I need to make a call to `orbit.foundation.js` anymore. Isn't that right?

Also, what happens is that the first image shows up and the autoplay starts when I click on the next arrow or the previous arrow but the image never slides. I've seen using inspect element of Chrome that the html of Orbit is rendered correctly and the CSS and JS files are all called or not. They are all fine. The slider shows correctly with all the controls but the images doesn't slide.

Am I missing something here? Please help.

**N.B.**

Tried other sliders (Owl Carousel Slider) too. Seems none works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using foundation.js instead of foundation.min.js and then included the foundation.orbit.js. Perhaps there may be some error which was caused by foundation.min.js.